# How to delete empathy chats - cannot find log file

Tags: empathy, delete, facebook

How to delete empathy facebook chats?
Tried to locate log file from:

```
./.local/share/Empathy/logs/
```

And:

```
~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs
```

But no such directories or files are present.

Tried to locate `ACCOUNT/USER/DATE.log` file but that is not present either.

Perhaps `DATE.log` file contains all system logs and not empathy log.

Is there any way delete empathy chats connected to my facebook account?

Comment: Are you sure these are actually stored on your computer? If I was to build a Facebook chat client, I would use the Facebook API to retrieve the chat history from Facebook, not store it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are stored in `./.local/share/Empathy/logs/` if stored locally (at least on older Ubuntu versions is was; have not used it a lot after I installed 14.10). If they are stored remotely this is probably the method to use ([kudos to Corbin052198@ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1793618&p=10998135#post10998135)):

1. Open the Empathy Buddy List.
2. Right-click on a user name, and click on 'Previous Conversations'.
3. Somewhere under the menus is an option to delete all chat history.
4. Select which accounts you want to clear the history of (or chose all of them) and click Clear.